# DataTable / DataHelper rows not empty via stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net-core

Just a little bit stuck and I can't seem to find what I am looking for on google.

For some reason this `If` statement produces rows and continues to run the code even when I know the stored procedure produces no results.

I have tried everything from

```
(rp.Rows[0] != null) / (rp.Rows.Count > 0)
```

and a combination of `&&` statements with no luck. I was under the impression all of these statements would only trigger if the stored procedure returned a row?

I am a little lost as to what exactly I am trying to find in the Microsoft documents too, appreciate the responses and direction someone may provide.

```
var rp = DataHelper.ExecuteStoredProcedure("[dbo].[Report]", newSqlParameter("@reportId", id));

if (rp.Rows.Any()) 
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: When you debug through - does `rp.Rows` contain anything? If you run `int count = rp.Rows.Count` - what value do you get?? Hard to say for anyone outside since that `DataHelper` doesn't look like a standard .NET class - so we cannot possibly know what's going on inside that class and what it returns ......

Comment: It is just a class holding the DataTable, I will see if I can get the program running in VS - debug. Glad to confirm I probably should have asked about this already thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.Any()` (or any other linq extension methods) on a DataRowCollection without first doing something like a `.Cast<DataRow>()`, because a DataRowCollection implements `IEnumerable`, not the `IEnumerable<T>` LINQ requires

```
if(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any())
```

---

This doesn't make sense to me:

```
(rp.Rows[0] != null) / (rp.Rows.Count > 0)
```

You cannot divide one boolean by another..

---

Also, this would crash if there were no rows:

```
rp.Rows[0] != null)
```

This would work fine and would detect if there were rows

```
rp.Rows.Count > 0
```

but is at odds with what you say you want:

> when I know the stored procedure produces no results.

If the sproc produces no rows and the code only runs when there are rows, then the code doesn't run

How about

```
if(rp.Rows.Count == 0)
  MessageBox.Show("no rows");
else
  foreach(DataRow r in rp.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine(r["some column name here"]);
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, I made a rookie mistake in thinking that my SP produced no rows when it was actually set to 'END' instead of no results, I have fixed it now and it works. Cheers, all your different ways are useful in this situation now.